# Counting even and odd number of letters in words

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently trying to count how many words from a textfile have even numbers and odd numbers of characters but I cant seem to get it to work. so far i have done

```
    int countEven = 0;
    int countOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <latinLength.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(latinLength.charAt(i))) {
            countEven++;
        } else {
            countOdd++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of unique even words in Latin names = " + countEven);
    System.out.println("Total number of unique odd words in Latin names = " + countOdd);
}
```

i think what i did wrong is i am not accessing the right part of the text file. i do have a get function for the information i want which is getLatinName, but i am not sure how to implement it correctly

```
    String tempLatinName = " ";
    String latinLength = " ";
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
        tempLatinName = info.get(i).getLatinName();      
        latinLength = tempLatinName.replace(" ","");
        letters += latinLength.length();
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of letters in all Latin names = " + letters);
```

i have edited the code to show the bit i have done before trying to calculate how many words have odd and even number of characters, the code above is to calculate the total number of characters in each word and then gives me a total

```
/**
*
* @author g_ama
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Task1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shark-data.txt"));
    String line;
    List<Shark> info = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] data = line.split(":");

        int MaxLength = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        int MaxDepth = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);
        int MaxYoung;
        try {
            MaxYoung = Integer.parseInt(data[4]);
        } catch (Exception X) {
            MaxYoung = -1;
        }
        int GlobalPresence = Integer.parseInt(data[5]);

        ArrayList<String> OceanicRegion = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] Region = data[6].split(",");
        for (String Element : Region) {
            OceanicRegion.add(Element);
        }

        Shark shark = new Shark(data[0], data[1], MaxLength, MaxDepth, MaxYoung, GlobalPresence, OceanicRegion);

        info.add(shark);
    }
    Collections.sort(info);
    System.out.println("The three largest sharks");
    System.out.println(info.get(info.size() - 1).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(info.size() - 1).MaxLength + " cm");
    System.out.println(info.get(info.size() - 2).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(info.size() - 2).MaxLength + " cm");
    System.out.println(info.get(info.size() - 3).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(info.size() - 3).MaxLength + " cm");

    System.out.println("The three smallest sharks");
    System.out.println(info.get(0).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(0).MaxLength + " cm");
    System.out.println(info.get(1).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(1).MaxLength + " cm");
    System.out.println(info.get(2).getCommonName() + ", " + info.get(2).MaxLength + " cm");

    //count total characters for Latin Name
    String tempLatinName = " ";
    String latinLength = " ";
    int letters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
        tempLatinName = info.get(i).getLatinName();
        latinLength = tempLatinName.replace(" ", "");
        letters += latinLength.length();
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of letters in all Latin names = " + letters);

    //count even or odd words
    int countEven = 0;
    int countOdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < latinLength.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(latinLength.charAt(i))) {
            countEven++;
        } else {
            countOdd++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of unique even words in Latin names = " + countEven);
    System.out.println("Total number of unique odd words in Latin names = " + countOdd);
}
```

}

Comment: Please show an example input, the desired output and what your program currently outputs. Also try to create a [mcve].

Comment: You're not doing what you set out to do. You're just counting letters and non-letters. Think about the logic of the problem more.

Comment: You will need to split the text into **words** (**tokenize**). After that, for each word, count the amount of characters. If it is an even number you may increase `countEven` by one. If the number is odd increase `countOdd` by one.

Comment: Post all of your code.

Comment: `latinLength` doesn't seem like a very good name for a string.

Comment: @Zabuza i have already split the list into words and removed any spaces for names with 2 words. Also the program should process and output without user input. it should read the file and choose the information from the text file.

Comment: So is `latinLength` a **word**? I.e. is there some kind of `for (String latinLength : words)` around the code you showed us?

Comment: @Zabuza yes it is a word, i will paste the bit before which i used to count the number of characters in Latin name and give me my result,        
        String tempLatinName = " ";
        String latinLength = " ";
        int letters = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
            tempLatinName = info.get(i).getLatinName();      
            latinLength = tempLatinName.replace(" ","");
            letters += latinLength.length();
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of letters in all Latin names = " + letters);   sorry for bad layout, not used to forum

Comment: Ah alright. You may **edit** the question instead, that would be awesome.

Comment: i just edited it

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want to ignore **non-letter characters** in **words** when counting their length? So is `ab1%1c` supposed to output a length of `3` or `6`?

Comment: the file only contains letters. when i run the program it should count how many words have an even number of characters and how many words have odd number of characters, i am not sure if i was supposed to use latinLength to try and do the bit i am trying to do now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Currently you are only counting how many **letters** and **non-letters** your text has. That is of course not the amount of **even words** or **odd words**.

For example if you have a word like

```
test12foo!$bar
```

Your code will currently output

```
countEven => 10  // Amount of letters (testfoobar)
countOdd  => 4   // Amount of non-letters (12!$)
```

Compare this to your **if-condition**:

```
if (Character.isLetter(latinLength.charAt(i))) {
    countEven++;
} else {
    countOdd++;
}
```

What you want is to count how often the length of your words is even or odd, so suppose words like

```
test     // length 4, even
foo      // length 3, odd
bartest  // length 7, odd
```

then you want

```
countEven => 1 // (test)
countOdd  => 2 // (foo, bartest)
```

---

### Solution

Instead you will need to **split** your text into **words** (tokenize). After that you will need to count, for each word, the amount of characters. If that is even you may increase `countEven` by one. Likewise `countOdd++` if it's an odd number.

The core will be this condition

```
word.length() % 2 == 0
```

it is `true` if the word has an **even** length and **false** if it's odd. You can easily verify this yourself (`%` returns the remainder after division, `0` or `1` in this case).

Let's assume your text structure is simple and words are always separated by `whitespace`, i.e. something like

```
test foo bar John Doe
```

All in all your code could then look like

```
Path path = Paths.get("myFile.txt");
AtomicInteger countEven = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger countOdd = new AtomicInteger(0);
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile(" ");

Files.lines(path)                         // Stream<String> lines
    .flatMap(wordPattern::splitAsStream)  // Stream<String> words
    .mapToInt(String::length)             // IntStream length
    .forEach(length -> {
        if (length % 2 == 0) {
            countEven.getAndIncrement();
        } else {
            countOdd.getAndIncrement();
        }
    });


System.out.println("Even words: " + countEven.get());
System.out.println("Odd words: " + countOdd.get());
```

Or without all that `Stream` stuff:

```
Path path = Paths.get("myFile.txt");

List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

// Read words
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] wordsOfLine = line.split(" ");
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList(wordsOfLine));
}

// Count even and odd words
int countEven = 0;
int countOdd = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    if (word.length() % 2 == 0) {
        countEven++;
    } else {
        countOdd++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Even words: " + countEven);
System.out.println("Odd words: " + countOdd);
```

---

### Adjusted to your specific code

As you've just added your specific code I'll add a solution adapted to it.

In your code the list `info` contains all `Shark`s. From those sharks the words you want to consider is represented by `Shark#getLatinName`. So all you will need to do is some kind of this:

```
List<String> words = info.stream()  // Stream<Shark> sharks
    .map(Shark::getLatinName)       // Stream<String> names
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and you can use this `words` exactly as shown in the other code examples. Alternatively you don't need to collect everything into a new list, you can directly stay in the `Stream` and continue with the stream-approach shown before. All in all:

```
AtomicInteger countEven = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger countOdd = new AtomicInteger(0);

info.stream()                             // Stream<Shark> sharks
    .map(Shark::getLatinName)             // Stream<String> names
    .mapToInt(String::length)             // IntStream length of names
    .forEach(length -> {
        if (length % 2 == 0) {
            countEven.getAndIncrement();
        } else {
            countOdd.getAndIncrement();
        }
    });

System.out.println("Even words: " + countEven);
System.out.println("Odd words: " + countOdd);
```

And substitute this into that part in your code:

```
//count even or odd words

(substitute here)
```

Comment: instead of doing line.split since ive already done that earlier as they had " : " inbetween each part, is it possible to do String[] wordsOfLine = getLatinName? or something along those lines as i am only trying to do this for one group of text in the text file, im sorry if my explanation of what i mean isnt clear, not the best at explaining things

Comment: Of course, you can completely exchange the file reading and splitting part if you've done that before. At some point you should have some kind of `List<String> words` ready, don't you? Just skip everything where I only setup that data-structure. Or in the `Stream` approach just skip the first two expressions and directly start with `words.stream().mapToInt(String::length).forEach(...)`.

Comment: I mean the important part is the last bit with the `if-else`. This decides whether a word has an odd or even length: `word.length() % 2 == 0`, **even** if `true` and **odd** if `false`.

Comment: so far i understand everything you have done and said, im just not sure how to write it to suit my code that ive done so far, i have the <list> but i did it differently i guess? unless im looking at the wrong part of my code and comparing? https://gyazo.com/17b9d8ab174b94da48499fc668d6bc6d here is a screenshot of what im comparing the first bit of your code to, the thing is i understand how u did it now, but im not sure how to link it to choose the specific part of my .txt file that i want it to say if its even or odd since i dont want it to do this for the entire text file

Comment: Does `data` contain all words? Then let this be the `words` I talked about in the last comments. Use `Arrays.stream(data)` for the `Stream` approach, the other approach will work without modification. Note that your way of reading file is **legacy**, nowadays one uses **NIO** (like seen in my approach).

Comment: this is why i used .getLatinName in the second part of coding i posted, yes data does, each group is split up, the one i need would need data[1] which is for the latin names

Comment: If that didn't help I must admit that you will need to **edit** your question and show the complete code ([mcve]). Otherwise it will be hard for us to give an answer that is more suited to your very specific code.

Comment: i have added the entire code, i have another separate class which i used to create the shark which has my get methods and toString methods

Comment: ive tried to adjust my code to suit mine and it gives me this as an output https://gyazo.com/c6ec3ff0587345c3361918359c57ef02

Comment: I see, after the edit it is clear. I've added a paragraph to the answer which shows an adapted version.